# What should I do to debug in Collision Detection?

Tags: unity-game-engine, collision-detection

There is a big bug in this script in Unity that I wanted to ask before changing the functions, is there an easier way to fix this bug? It is a simple game that if the ball hits the cylinder in the middle of the field for 5 seconds, the first cylinder will come down and the player will win. The bug is that if the ball hits the cylinder in a very short time and returns very quickly, the ground will not notice and the timer will continue and after 5 seconds the cylinder will come down and win.

```
void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
{
    if (collision.gameObject.CompareTag("Cylinder"))
    {
        collisionTime = Time.time;
        timerActive = true;
        cylinderObject = collision.gameObject;
    }
    else if (collision.gameObject.CompareTag("Ground"))
    {
        timerActive = false;
        UpdateTimerText();
    }
}

void Update()
{
    if (timerActive && Time.time - collisionTime > collisionThreshold)
    {
        restarting = true;

        if (cylinderObject != null)
        {
            Vector3 newPosition = cylinderObject.transform.position;
            newPosition.y -= 2f;
            cylinderObject.transform.position = newPosition;                
            timerActive = false;               
        }
        
        StartCoroutine(RestartGameAfterDelay(restartDelay));
    }

    UpdateTimerText();
}

IEnumerator RestartGameAfterDelay(float delay)
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(delay);
    SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex);
}

void UpdateTimerText()
{
    if (restarting)
    {
        timerText.text = "";
        return;
    }

    if (timerText != null)
    {
        float remainingTime = Mathf.Max(0f, collisionThreshold - (Time.time - collisionTime));

        if (timerActive)
        {
            timerText.text = $"Time: {remainingTime:F1}s";
        }
        else
        {
            timerText.text = "";
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: dont you want to just reset your timer to max if it hits ground?

Comment: I did this, but it still didn't work.

Comment: Maybe rather use `OnCollisionExit` to determine when contact has left the cylinder? If the ground had started being collided with at the same time as the cylinder, the cancellation of the timer would not happen. Or just remove the `else` in from of the `else if` statement so that the cancellation would happen in this case. This is not a the most optimal method though as you'd be running the first block for no reason.